# getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet trying to create new Instance (jsf 2.0 -> 2.2 migration issue?)

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, myfaces

For some reason (wonder why....) After my bean in being created (as a result of ValueExpressionImpl: `#{admin.userLocale}` (I see it in the stack-trace in the break-point of the constructor), tight after that when my phaselistener is failing (exception) in invoking the following command

```
return context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context,
            "#{myBean}", myBean.class);
```

The execution of the code above triggers the constructor for the second time - why?

The weird thing is that I got the exact mechanism working just fine (bean constructor call -> phase listener invoking "the" command (which not calling beans constructor again)) in many others apps... but in that particular app its not working.

**Also an important note that with MyFaces 2.0.11 this app works just fine**

I double and triple checked that faces-config / web.xml are like in other apps too

The exception that I'm getting after moving from MyFaces JSF 2.0.11 to 2.2.3 is:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /viewMetadata/myPage.xhtml at line 13 and column 38 locale="#{myBean.userLocale}" null

...

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.getScope(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:560)

I did a bit of Google and found the following [MYFACES-3907](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3907) and I even tried to apply the fix but all it did is removing the exception but my webapp still no good

p.s Its a s `@SessionScoped` and the Phase Id in which the `getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet` is being called is `RESTORE_VIEW`

Any Ideas on how can I figure out what causes the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't specify the scope of the given bean, nor in which phase of the lifecycle you're calling the method...

Comment: Its a s `@SessionScoped` and the Phase Id is `RESTORE_VIEW`

Comment: Was you also migrating to a different CDI environment? CDI calls the constructor when creating proxies. You'd better do business job in `@PostConstruct`. To naildown the one responsible for calling the constructor, put a breakpoint and explore the stack or do a `Thread.dumpStack()` in constructor.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the tip, will continue with the `breakpoint` , I don't do business in the constructor, I created it only for logging and the `breakpoint` thing from the first place... The code from jsf that call the first Bean instance is `#{myBean.userLocale}` , that from my `PhaseListener` the `getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet`  is called (same flow in all my web apps)

Comment: @BalusC, I updated the question/title with more clear and detailed flow

Comment: Can't reproduce in a blank project with MyFaces 2.2.3 on Tomcat 7.0.53.

Comment: @BalusC, Thanks for trying to help, as I said , the exact setup works on several other apps... so my guess that this particular app got some sort of "garbage" that worked well in 2.0.11 but not in 2.2.3, I spent two days now.. and counting :/ to try to figure out whats wrong and where is that "garbage" is... what is that something that was allowed in 2.0.11 but not in 2.2.3 :'( opened issue on myfaces too https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3922 , so annoying... (I'm basically deleted all the content of the project now and reverting it back file by file....) Thanks again :|

Comment: Is that environment (implicitly) using CDI? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: @BalusC, I'm not using CDI, but I did found the problem (posted an answer) thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem... although I don't really know why (do have some theories)

In that bean of mine there was a `ManagedProperty`...

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{error}")
private ErrorPageMBean error;  //with getter/setter
```

That managed property was there for years and wasn't even used. and again it all worked just fine in MyFaces 2.0.11...

The moment I removed it all started to works just fine...

Any idea whats wrong with that `ManagedProperty` ?